# Access array inside object array

Tags: c#, arrays, .net-core

```
System.Object[] ArrayTest = new System.Object[2] 
{ 
     new System.Int32[]{  10  },
     new System.Byte[]{ 1,4,6 }
};
```

How to access `System.Int32` and `System.Byte` from the System.Object Array [?]

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

```
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show( ((System.Int32)ArrayTest[0][0]).ToString() ); //Something Like That;
```

Solved By [clemens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1136211/clemens)

```
var i = ((int[])ArrayTest[0])[0]; //[?] Solution; Return : 10;
```

---

#### Updated Complexity

```
System.Object[] ArrayTest = new System.Object[3] 
{ 
     new System.Int32[]{  10  },
     new System.Byte[]{ 1,4,6 },
     new System.Object[2]{
         new System.Int32[]{  100  },
         new System.Byte[]{ 1,4,6 },
     }
};
```

to access the second level array ::

```
var i = ((int[])((object[])ArrayTest[2])[0])[0];  //[?] Solution; Return : 100;
```

Comment: `var i = ((int[])ArrayTest[0])[0];`

Comment: This isn't a great way to store two arrays. Please do something that preserves type instead, e.g. put them in a simple struct or value tuple.

Comment: Very well; got around to know the single dimmensional then went to JaggedArrays; and then got no idea what was going on;

Comment: C# already has that class by the way: Tuple<int[], byte[]>

Comment: the type where to be preserved through method logics;

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
object[][] ArrayTest = new[]
{
    (new int[]{ 1 }).Cast<object>().ToArray(),
    (new byte[]{ 4, 6, 8 }).Cast<object>().ToArray(),
};
```

Comment: The question is asking about accessing items (see the 2nd code block), not declaring the array.

Comment: It is possible to access it like he said: (int)ArrayTest[0][0]